# Recursively moving all files to one folder keeping the largest

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I've got a big folder of images that I need to combine, and I've managed the first step using the following:

```
find ./products_raw -type f -exec cp {} products_processed  \;
```

However the folder structure they are coming from also includes thumbnails of the same name so it's down to luck which size image ends up in the folder. My logic is that if I can check if the file is larger then chances are it'll be the right one. Not sure how to achieve this, the usual searches aren't showing anything too clear.

Cheers!

EDIT: Should have mentioned, I'm using OSX

Answer (score 2):

Well, the answer is rather simple.

First you get list of files with their sizes:

```
find . -type f -printf '%s\t%f\t%p\n'
```

There will be 3 columns: size, filename, file path (with name).

Then you sort it by size, to make larger files earlier:

```
find . -type f -printf '%s\t%f\t%p\n' | sort -nr
```

then, you pass it through awk to remove repeating filenames:

```
find . -type f -printf '%s\t%f\t%p\n' | \
    sort -nr | \
    awk -F'\t' '!c[$2]++ {print $3}'
```

and finally, you copy the files to your destination directory:

```
find . -type f -printf '%s\t%f\t%p\n' | \
    sort -nr | \
    awk -F'\t' '!c[$2]++ {print $3}' | \
    xargs -d'\n' cp -t wherever/
```

Comment: Very clearly explained, thank you. Unfortunately I realised I'd neglected to mention I'm on OSX and as a result it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Do it step by step, and fix whatever you can. I can't change it to OSX-compatible, because I don't have anything with OSX to test it on.

Comment: I'll give it a go, cheers. Thanks for spending the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-size` test for the `find` command, e.g. to find all files larger than 1 MB:

```
find ./products_raw -type f -size +1M -exec cp {} products_processed \;
```

Comment: This will cause issues with duplicated files where both of them are over 1MB, or when largest file with given name is  (for example) 500K.